# GVim shift+space mapped to something strange

Tags: vim

Using **gvim 7.3.524** on RHEL 5.4 I'm frustrated by the mapping for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> when in insert mode. It changes the characters into some strange garbage

Typing the same sequence of characters:

`ABC123abc123`  <-- normal insert

`¤Ô23¹¤º123` <-- after pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in insert mode

Note this does not happen in regular vim, just gvim.

If I try remapping with: `imap <S-Space> zO` it has no effect. This is driving me batty.

Comment: `<S-Space>` is not mapped to anything by default. What is the output of `:verbose imap <S-space>`?

Comment: It could be a deliberate switch of language encoding before the keys even get to Vim (see http://www.maruko.ca/i18n/ for example). Does the same happen after pressing Shift+Space any other GUI editors?